# Latex code for adjusting attributes of hline (color, dashed), and/or attributes of vertical lines in table

Tags: colors, latex, line, pdflatex

I want to color hline, e.g.:

```
\hline[color=red,width=2mm,dashed]
```

or something.

Below is a feeble attempt which fails. I put textcolor gray around `{|}` to try and make it gray.  Ideally, I want it gray and dashed.  Also note textcolor gray around the `{\hline}` tag.  Any help would be appreciated using latex syntax.

Are there attributes for `\hline`? If so, where is the documentation?.  There is a reason I love php.net for my other programing needs.

```
    \begin{array}{c\textcolor{gray}{|}cccccccccc}
 & \textcolor{gray}{P_1} & \textcolor{gray}{P_2} & \textcolor{gray}{P_3} & \textcolor{gray}{P_4}  & \textcolor{gray}{P_5} & \textcolor{gray}{P_6} & \textcolor{gray}{P_7} & \textcolor{gray}{P_8} & \textcolor{gray}{P_9} & \textcolor{gray}{P_{10}}\\
 \textcolor{gray}{\hline}
\textcolor{gray}{P_1}   &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_2}   & 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_3}   &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_4}   &0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_5}   &1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_6}   &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_7}   &1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_8}   &1&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_9}   &0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\textcolor{gray}{P_{10}}  &0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0
\end{array}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, import the color package, like so:

```
\usepackage{color}
```

And then use the [arydshln package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arydshln), and do this (in a tabular context):

```
\textcolor{gray}{\hdashline}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the official packages ;)

Write following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%It sets your colour line and then sets back to default (black)
\newcommand{\grayline}{\arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline\arrayrulecolor{black}}
```

Use `\grayline` exactly like `\hline` in your table.

Comment: nice! how to set the thickness of the line?

Comment: @WizardofKneup, I help Wizards only under the condition that they do not use my help to perform any spells. In the example of [this  TeX SX question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124155/variable-width-horizontal-rules-with-cline-intrude-cell-text) you have the code to change the length. You are a clever guy, I am sure you'll get to combine both codes ;).

Comment: So it's `\arrayrulewidth`. Thanks!